# return a value from while loop when using asyncio function

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

I am trying to connect and recieve messages from multiple websockets concurrently.
For this purpose I made it with asyncio, and it prints messages correctly. But the problem is that I just can print it, not  return it.

The simplified example of pseudo code which I am struggle with is as below:

```
import websockets
import json

symbols_id = [1,2]

## LOOP RUNNING EXAMPLE OF ASYNCIO
async def get_connect(symbols_id):
    tasks = []
    for _id in symbols_id:
        print('conncetion to', _id)
        if _id == 1:
            a = 0
        elif _id == 2:
            a = 200
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(_loop(a)))

    return tasks

async def _loop(a):
    while True:
        print(a)
        a+=1
        await asyncio.sleep(2.5)

async def ping_func():
    while True:
        print('------ ping')
        await asyncio.sleep(5)


async def main():
    tasks = await get_connect(symbols_id)
    asyncio.create_task(ping_func())
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

asyncio.run(main())
```

As you can see from the code above I used `print(a)` to print `a` in each loop.
I test `return a` instead of `print(a)` but it was not helpful.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

`yield a`? `return a` will exit the function and the loop, `yield` is usually what you want in asyncio for looped tasks

Comment: I tried `yield` but confused with how to get result.
I know which `async for` is the thing which must be use with `yield` but I don't know where.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the way of using `yield` and `async for` to read data in each loop.
It will work correctly, by changing the code to the following one.

```
import websockets
import json

symbols_id = [1,2]

global a
a=0

## LOOP RUNNING EXAMPLE OF ASYNCIO
async def get_connect(symbols_id):
    tasks = []
    for _id in symbols_id:
        print('conncetion to', _id)
        if _id == 1:
            a = 0
        elif _id == 2:
            a = 200
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(_loop(a)))

    return tasks

async def _loop(param):
    global a
    a = param
    while True:
        print(a)
        a+=1
        await asyncio.sleep(2.5)

async def ping_func():
    while True:
        print('------ ping')
        await asyncio.sleep(5)

async def get_result():
    global a
    while True:
        yield a
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main():
    tasks = await get_connect(symbols_id)
    asyncio.create_task(ping_func())
    async for x in get_result():
        print(x)
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

asyncio.run(main())
```

I was confused with how to use generated data from this code snippet inside the other code snippet. what I found is:

1- Generated data can be accessible with global variables.

2- By defining a class and a property, it can be accessible from every part of the code.